# Getting unexpected results when shifting a 32-bit integer more than 32 times

Tags: c, bit-shift

I would like clarification on why some bit shifting is doing something I wouldn't expect.

I developed a function, `setBitsVersion1` that sets bits to 1 in an array of 32 bit integers using the regular `int` primitive type. So this means that bit positions [0, 31] are for the first integer in the array, bit positions [32, 63] are for the second integer in the array etc. For example, position 10 is position 10 at the first integer, but position 35 is really position 3 in the second integer. So, if `bitPosition` were 35, then `line 4` would become `a[1] = a[1] | one << 3` thus setting the bit at position 3. This function behaves as expected, and you can see in the output when it prints the integers, the integer that prints is correct since the bit for the binary 2^3 position was set.

However, the next part is where I'm confused. I wrote a second implementation, `setBitsVersion2`, that gets rid of line `line 3` so the original bitPosition is never modified to be the correct bit position at a particular index. So, using 35 again the line would become `a[1] = a[1] | one << 35`. It's my understanding that left shifting 32 bits or more is undefined behavior. I'm not exactly sure what I would expect to print, but I definitely wouldn't of expected it to set the bit at position 3 because `1 << 35` is not `1 << 3` and shifting by 35 times is undefined behavior. Maybe I would've expected the integer to be zero, since in the past when I've shifted integers 32 times or more, it just ends up being 0. Regardless, I'm just confused as to why doing `1 << 35` produces the same results `1 << 3` since I would've expected it not to work and would like an explanation.

And in case the kind of machine/compiler I'm using is relevant, then I'm on a Windows computer using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. Though, I also tested it out on Linux using gcc and got the same results.

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setBitVersion1(int* a, int bitPosition);
void setBitVersion2(int* a, int bitPosition);
void printArray(int* a, int size);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Correct implementation - setBitsVersion1 - results are correct and what is expected\n");
    int a1[5] = { 0 };
    int a1Size = sizeof(a1) / sizeof(*a1);
    setBitVersion1(a1, 35);
    setBitVersion2(a1, 67);
    printArray(a1, a1Size);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Incorrect version - setBitsVersion2 - still produces the same results?\n");
    int a2[5] = { 0 };
    int a2Size = sizeof(a2) / sizeof(*a2);
    setBitVersion1(a2, 35);
    setBitVersion2(a2, 67);
    printArray(a2, a2Size);

    return 0;
}

void setBitVersion1(int* a, int bitPosition) {
    int one = 1;                                // line 1
    int index = bitPosition / 32;               // line 2
    bitPosition = bitPosition % 32;             // line 3
    a[index] = a[index] | one << bitPosition;   // line 4
}

void setBitVersion2(int* a, int bitPosition) {
    int one = 1;
    int index = bitPosition / 32;
    a[index] = a[index] | one << bitPosition;
}

void printArray(int* a, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Correct implementation - setBitsVersion1 - results are correct and what is expected
0
8
8
0
0


Incorrect version - setBitsVersion2 - still produces the same results?????
0
8
8
0
0
```

Comment: Shifting an integer more than the bits allocated for it leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: ^^^^ https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior#Bit_shifting_using_negative_counts_or_beyond_the_width_of_the_type

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I understand that it's undefined behavior and said that in my comment. I was just wondering if there was some deeper explanation aside from it being the result of undefined behavior.

Comment: "_I was just wondering if there was some deeper explanation aside from it being the result of undefined behavior._" Undefined behaviour = Not guarenteed to behave in a certain specific way by the standard. In other words, compiler-dependant or architecture-dependant.

Comment: While all behavior can be explained from knowing how it's handled by a specific compiler using specific settings (optimization on or off etc.), generally speaking any generic or general  speculation about undefined behavior is moot. It might cause crashes, unexpected result, set your neighbors cat on fire, perhaps [summon nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). It might even seem to work just fine. To see what your compiler using your settings do, look at the generated assembly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 << 35` can produce `1 << 3` because the machine instruction for shifting a 32-bit value has only five bits in the field for the shift amount. When 35 (binary 100011) is used, the processor sees only five bits (00011), which is 3, so it shifts by 3 bits. Of course, other behaviors are possible; the compiler might calculate the shift itself using more complicated software while compiling or might use a different instruction with different behavior.

> It's my understanding that left shifting 32 bits or more is undefined behavior. I'm not exactly sure what I would expect to print, but I definitely wouldn't [have] expected it to set the bit at position 3 because 1 << 35 is not 1 << 3 and shifting by 35 times is undefined behavior.

Of course you “wouldn't have expected” it to set the bit at position 3 or do anything else in particular, because the C standard does not give you any expectation. To have an expectation, you must have some grounds for expecting, such as statements in the C standard about how it should behave or familiarity with how compilers are written or knowledge of processor instructions. Be on guard for expecting certain things to occur—or even for expecting certain things not to occur—when you do not have grounds for it.

Answer (score 3):

> more is undefined behavior. I'm not exactly sure what I would expect to print, but I definitely wouldn't of expected it to set the bit at position 3 because 1 << 35 is not 1 << 3 and shifting by 35 times is undefined behavior.

This is exactly how you should approach undefined behavior. Nice.

> why doing 1 << 35 produces the same results 1 << 3 since I would've expected it not to work

Undefined behavior means that you have *no expectations*, not that it "will not work". It may "work" in an unpredictable manner, it may crash, it may spawn [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). No one knows.

You can inspect *your specific compiler assembly output for the specific options you have used*, and you can discover, for example using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/16dYMhT56), that your compiler on x86_64 happens to use `sal     edx, cl` assembly instruction for left shifting. Remember, that *there is no guarantee* of any kind, and in case of undefined behavior, *anything* can happen. As you noted - you can't "expect".

From https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html I can read:

> The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31

So even if a value greater than `31` is stored inside `CL` register, it is marked to 5 bits anyway *on this specific architecture*.

Note, that the compiler, given for example different compiler options, undef different optimization levels in particular, or a different version of the compiler *might* generate a different instruction to do the shifting.

---

You should use `uint32_t`.

You are using an `int` type to represent any kind of bit values pattern. Your `setBitVersion1` has undefined behavior, the standard says [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4) :

> The result of E1 << E2 is .... If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

`one << bitPosition` when `bitPosition = 31` results in... `2^31`, which is greater than an `int` can represent `INT_MAX = 2^31 - 1`. This is undefined behavior - your code is actually safe for `bitPosition` lower or equal 30.

`int` and `unsiggned int` types have **at least** 16 bits. They have 16 bits on some compilers for small microcontrollers.

Use `intX_t` types to represent specific count of types. Use unsigned types with `<<` `>>`.